# Access class function from different cpp (how to declare)

Tags: c++, qt, class, function, header

I have a problem with my Qt(c++) class.

Code:

SharedVariables.h

```
class SharedVariables
{
    private:
        QString TextoPesquisa;
        bool LoginEfectuado;

    public:
        SharedVariables();
        QString getTextoPesquisa();
        void setTextoPesquisa(QString TxtPesquisa);
        bool getLoginUtilizador();
        void setLoginUtilizador(bool UtilizadorComLogin);
};
```

SharedVariables.cpp

```
QString ShareVariables::getTextoPesquisa()
{
    return TextoPesquisa;
}

void ShareVariables::setTextoPesquisa(QString TxtPesquisa)
{
    TextoPesquisa = TxtPesquisa;
}

bool ShareVariables::getLoginUtilizador()
{
    return LoginEfectuado;
}

void ShareVariables::setLoginUtilizador(bool UtilizadorComLogin)
{
    LoginEfectuado = UtilizadorComLogin;
}
```

Then to have access to the functions in my 2 (or more) cpp's, I use this :

File1.cpp (the one who writes)

```
SharedVariables e1;
e1.setTextoPesquisa("StringHERE");
```

File1.cpp (the one who reads)

```
SharedVariables e2;
qDebug() << e2.getTextoPesquisa();
```

The problem is that when the e2 is initialized my QString TextoPesquisa becomes empty again, And i don't know who to solve this problem, since I want that the values stay the same so I can access everywhere with this functions.

Comment: Isn't e1 and e2 two different objects ? Or did you do an assignment or copy somewhere or something ?

Comment: I recommend learning how OOP works, including the difference between a class and an object.

Comment: @dark_charlie : I've already solved the problem (thanks to Donotalo) but did you have a nice tutorial so I can take a look at that ?

Comment: try for example this one: http://www.gillius.org/ooptut/index.htm

Answer (score 2):

The variable need to be [static](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/811-static-member-variables/):

```
class SharedVariables
{
    private:
        static QString TextoPesquisa;
```

Also make sure you declare `TexttoPesquisa` in cpp file:

```
QString SharedVariables::TextoPesquisa;
```

Because static variables aren't bound to particular class instance, they need their own memory location.

Answer (score 0):

e2 is empty because you are using two different instances of the same class.

You need to create a SharedVariables object (on your main for example) and then use it on your various classes in .cpp files.

Comment: a SharedVariable object ?... you mine like this : "SharedVariables MyVariables;" and then call like this MyVariables.getTextoPesquisa(); ? When talkin to memory usage, what is the best ? the static solution or create a Class Object at the start of the software ?

Comment: In my opinion you should avoid static(global) variables whenever possible. However, considering memory usage, either option shouldn't have a significant impact.

Comment: I can avoid the static variables only if I found a way to use the same variable in a class during all the usage of the software by the user. I've tried to create the SharedVariables object in the main but I don't know how to call it in others sources (cpp) files :S

Comment: Every .cpp file is a different class (at least, it should be). To call SharedVariables from different classes, you need to initiallize those classes with a pointer to SharedVariables, or use methods that receive references to SharedVariables. I would advise you to read a little bit more about c++. Here is a very good (and free) book: http://www.mindview.net/Books/TICPP/ThinkingInCPP2e.html